# Get the number of 429 (throughput exceeded) exceptions caused by a Cosmos DB query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to use the .NET `CosmosClient` for Cosmos DB NoSQL to retrieve the number of library-internal 429 exceptions caused by a query?

Perhaps with `FeedResponse<T>.Diagnostics.GetFailedRequestCount()`? I'm not quite sure what precisely is meant by "[failed requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosdiagnostics.getfailedrequestcount?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-cosmosdiagnostics-getfailedrequestcount)".